# Android Layouts Scrolling in Landscaped Mode

Tags: android

I have a strange issue in which on rotating the Screen to Landscaped mode the Views present inside Remain at the same place But I cannot scroll them inside the screen.

How can I make them Scroll so that every thing that move out should be displayed properly to the user.

Should there be any more attribute to be set for allowing such kind of behavior.

Comment: you should post your view code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys forgive for this... Figured out Pretty Simple Way out is to Put Everything inside a ScrollView so that everything inside them are able to scroll in proper Way...